# Firebase auth unit testing error No Firebase App

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to test my `firebase auth` methods. Auth methods are signin, signout , register, etc.
this are methods i want to perform unit test.

I'm getting error `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()`

I tried to initialize `Firebase.initializeApp` in test `main` method its also doesn't work.

```
 class MockUserRepository extends Mock implements AuthService {
  final MockFirebaseAuth auth;
  MockUserRepository({this.auth});
 }
 class MockFirebaseAuth extends Mock implements FirebaseAuth{}
 class MockFirebaseUser extends Mock implements FirebaseUser{}
 class MockFirebase extends Mock implements Firebase{}
 void main() {
   MockFirebase firebase=MockFirebase();
   MockFirebaseAuth _auth = MockFirebaseAuth();
   BehaviorSubject<MockFirebaseUser> _user = BehaviorSubject<MockFirebaseUser>();
   when(_auth.onAuthStateChanged).thenAnswer((_){
      return _user;
     });
   AuthService _repo = AuthService.instance(auth: _auth);
   group('user repository test', (){
       when(_auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: "email",password: "password")).thenAnswer((_)async{
  _user.add(MockFirebaseUser());
});
when(_auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: "mail",password: "pass")).thenThrow((){
  return null;
});
test("sign in with email and password", () async {
  var signedIn = await _repo.onLogin(email:"testuser@test.com",password: "123456");
  expect(signedIn, isNotNull);
  expect(_repo.status, Status.Authenticated);
});

test("sing in fails with incorrect email and password",() async {
  var signedIn = await _repo.onLogin(email:"testuser@test.com",password: "666666");
  expect(signedIn, false);
  expect(_repo.status, Status.Unauthenticated);
});

test('sign out', ()async{
  await _repo.signout();
  expect(_repo.status, Status.Unauthenticated);
 });
});
}
```

AuthService class

```
    enum Status { Uninitialized, Authenticated, Authenticating, 
    Unauthenticated }

   class AuthService with ChangeNotifier {
     FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
     FirebaseUser _user;

    FirebaseUser get user => _user;

    set user(FirebaseUser value) {
      _user = value;
    }

    Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;

    Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
      User currentUser;
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
      currentUser = user;
      });
      return currentUser;
     }
    AuthService();
    AuthService.instance({this.auth}) {
       //    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      //      onAuthStateChanged(user);
      //    });
      }

     Future<void> signout() async {
     await auth.signOut();
       }

     Future<User> createAccount({String email, String password}) async {
        try {
           UserCredential userCredential = await 
                  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
             email: email, password: password);
            return userCredential != null ? userCredential.user : null;
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
           showToast(e.message);
          } catch (e) {
          log(e.toString());
           return null;
          }
       }

     Future<User> onLogin({String email, String password}) async {
      try {
        User user;
           await auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
      .then((value) {
        showToast("Login sucessful");
       user = value != null ? value.user : null;
      });
      return user;
     } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showToast(e.message);
     }
    }

    sendResetPassword({String email}) async {
      bool isSent = false;
      try {
         await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email).then((value) {
           showToast("Reset password email sent");
            isSent = true;
        });
        return isSent;
       } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
           showToast(e.message);
    }
  }

    Future<void> onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseUser user) async {
     if (user == null) {
       _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
        } else {
        _user = user;
        _status = Status.Authenticated;
       }
       notifyListeners();
     }

     Status get status => _status;

     set status(Status value) {
        _status = value;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Which line of code causes that error?

Comment: @DougStevenson `AuthService _repo = AuthService.instance(auth: _auth);` this line please help. And i have also added my `AuthService` class .

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at how they tested directly in firebase_auth code : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/test

Call the `setupFirebaseAuthMocks` (you can adapt the code from [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/test/mock.dart)) method at the beginning of your `main` method and call `await Firebase.initializeApp();` in a `setUpAll` method.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. Just for clarification, you can pick the `mock_auth.dart` file over there and bring it to your test suite and use it.

Comment: Great answer, ty. Is there any way we can import this file from dependencies? I can't find it in the packages from pub.dev.

Comment: it has a severe issue - a lot of internal code needs to be known and copied over to your project to do something as basic as testing your components that use firebase. I'm surprised this hasn't been published as a library yet

Answer (score -2):

`Firebase.initializeApp()` is the solution for this. I am pretty sure. Try calling it in the file your are doing all these functions in their initState().

Comment: I have tried to `Firebase.initializeApp()` in my test file its also didn't work.