# How to mock the FirebaseApp in flutter

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, mocking

I am trying to test a method that uses FirebaseFirestore but I am not able to mock the FirebaseFirestore.instance property.

I am following these examples:

1. Initializing the core: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initializing-flutterfire
2. Using the firestore plugin: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

I am using the code below for my class and it is working well, which means the firestoreInstance is loaded correctly

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    Main(firebaseApp: Firebase.initializeApp()),
  );
}

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> firebaseApp;
  const Main({this.firebaseApp});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: firebaseApp,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(
            app: snapshot.data,
          );
          return MyWidget();
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But when I run the test below I got the message:

"The following FirebaseException was thrown building Builder(dirty):
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()"

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockFirebaseApp extends Mock implements FirebaseApp {}

void main() {
  FirebaseApp firebaseApp;

  setUp(() async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    firebaseApp = MockFirebaseApp();
  });

  group('Main', () {
    testWidgets('Loads my widget', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.runAsync(() async {
        await tester.pumpWidget(
          Main(firebaseApp: Future.value(firebaseApp)),
        );

        expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Firebase App '\[DEFAULT\]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in)

Comment: No, this link shows how to implement the class, I am doing exactly that and it works like a charm.

My problem is in the unit-test, because I don't know how to mock the Firebase.initializeApp() method, in my example in the description I am using Mockito to Mock the return of the call that is an FirebaseApp object

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mocking the _Firebase.initializeApp()_ method. While _Mockito_ works great for all purpose mocking, I would like to point out that there also exists _[Mock Cloud Firestore](https://github.com/atn832/cloud_firestore_mocks)_ which can be closer to what you need for Firestore. [Mock Clou Firestore in Flutter documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore_mocks)

Comment: What I want with "mocking the Firebase.initializeApp() method" is quite simple.
I want to receive a FirebaseApp instance that works when the unit-test reaches the FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor( app: MOCKED_MY_FIREBASEAPP_INSTANCE, )

Indeed Mockito works great mocking the method, but it's returned object does not work in the FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor method

I have checked the CloudFirestore Mock project, maybe I can use it, but for that, I will need to do a considerable refactoring in my code. I've tried to use it only to get a FirebaseApp instance, but it also had not worked for me.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63701588/5996264) I found the solution.

1. Copy the contents of: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/test/mock.dart into a file, that you can import into your tests, where you need to initialize a Firebase app.
2. Call `setupFirebaseAuthMocks();` at the top of your `main` function for all your tests.
3. In your `setUpAll` function, call `await Firebase.initializeApp();` (You can also put this in your `main` function under `setupFirebaseAuthMocks();` will still work).

Now you should have a mocked Firebase app.

Here is a full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import '../lib/authentication/your_auth_using_firebase.dart';
import './mock.dart'; // from: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/test/mock.dart



void main() {
  // TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); Gets called in setupFirebaseAuthMocks()
  setupFirebaseAuthMocks();

  setUpAll(() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  });

  testWidgets('Your Test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final YourFirebaseAuthClass authService = YourFirebaseAuthClass();
    // Tests to write
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Not the cleaner way to test it but it works for me too.

Comment: Gareth - great callout but doesn't seem to work with firebase crashlytics in the app, or at least i'm getting assertion errors there

Comment: thanks this does give me a good start but also firebase messaging throws MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Messaging#startBackgroundIsolate on
channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)

Comment: Great Start, thank you. Is there any way to cleanly import the mocks?

Comment: thank you very much friend. I spent about 4 hours trying various implementations. this was what i needed.

Comment: damn, spent days on this...thank you

Comment: So simple in the end! I was stuck on that and no clear documentation to be found... Thanks you a lot ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [fake_cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_cloud_firestore) package is useful for you:

> Fakes to write unit tests for Cloud Firestore. Instantiate a MockFirestoreInstance, then pass it around your project as if it were a FirestoreInstance. This fake acts like Firestore except it will only keep the state in memory. To help debug, you can use MockFirestoreInstance.dump() to see what's in the fake database. This is useful to set up the state of your database, then check that your UI behaves the way you expect.

Example from the docs:

```
import 'package:fake_cloud_firestore/fake_cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() {
  final instance = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
  await instance.collection('users').add({
    'username': 'Bob',
  });
  final snapshot = await instance.collection('users').get();
  print(snapshot.docs.length); // 1
  print(snapshot.docs.first.get('username')); // 'Bob'
  print(instance.dump());
}
```

In a UI test you would (example from the docs):

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:fake_cloud_firestore/fake_cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firestore_example/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

const MessagesCollection = 'messages';
    
        

void main() {
  testWidgets('shows messages', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Populate the fake database.
    final firestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
    await firestore.collection(MessagesCollection).add({
      'message': 'Hello world!',
      'created_at': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });

    // Render the widget.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        title: 'Firestore Example', home: MyHomePage(firestore: firestore)));
    // Let the snapshots stream fire a snapshot.
    await tester.idle();
    // Re-render.
    await tester.pump();
    // // Verify the output.
    expect(find.text('Hello world!'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('Message 1 of 1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

**EDIT:** For those combing from [cloud_firestore_mocks](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore_mocks) the author renamed this package to [fake_cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_cloud_firestore).

**DI:** You might also want to have a look at [`get_it`](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it), which allows you to combine things with dependency injection. This is helpful for component tests in which you want to instantiate a service that depends on the mock Firestore. Make everything you need to mock out a constructor parameter and inject it using `get_it`. In the tests you can then inject the `fake_cloud_firestore` mocks if you want to instantiate such a service.

Answer (score 3):

TO mock Firebase app you can use the following method from `firerbase_core_plarform_interface` plugin.

```
import 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

typedef Callback = void Function(MethodCall call);

void setupFirebaseAuthMocks([Callback? customHandlers]) {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  setupFirebaseCoreMocks();
}

Future<T> neverEndingFuture<T>() async {
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 5));
  }
}
```

Comment: why is this not the top/accepted answer ?

Answer (score 0):

think that is for use FutureBuilder as first Widget o root widget of the tree, flutter needs always a MaterialApp or others(dont remmember right now).

Recomendation, refactor FutureBuilder -> Wrap whit widget -> MaterialApp(home:FutureBuilder(...

and check MyWidget() first widget, maybe same MaterialApp get error, but not sure.

if you are using routes method to navigate use initialRoute.

Luck!

Comment: I can do this, but the problem will be the same, my problem is trying to mock the return of the Firebase.initializeApp() method, which means, I need to mock a FirebaseApp object that works in FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(
            app: MY_MOCKED_OBJECT,
          )