# How do I initialize Firebase App in Flutter widget testing

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am new in flutter and trying to perform widget testing on my app, but I am keep getting this weird error.
below is my test file

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:folk_team_app/provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:folk_team_app/screens/phone_login.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  Widget loginScreen = ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(
      create: (context) => AuthProvider(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: PhoneLogineScreen(),
        );
      });

  testWidgets('Phone Authetication Page', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.

    await tester.pumpWidget(loginScreen);
    await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 10));
    

    final titleText = find.text('Screen Title');

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(titleTextt, findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

here is the error  :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't add screenshots, just copy logs/errors as code

Comment: You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64730015/5996264) that solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly test Firebase because it requires platform configurations in order to initialize it properly.
You need to mock Firebase in the test environment using [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito).

You may find this [comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/896#issuecomment-554706154) and [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uB5_REsREtU&list=PLUiueC0kTFqLvpFk_Zg55geh_TBTKnbnA&index=5) helpful.