# Flutter Integration Test: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Auth#registerIdTokenListener

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, mocking, integration-testing

How do I mock firebase_auth methods in my integration tests?

I am getting the following error:

`MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Auth#registerIdTokenListener on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)`

The integration test currenlty doesn't do much:

```
void main() async {

  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  setupFirebaseAuthMocks();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  MockFirebaseAuth(signedIn: false);

  app.main();

}
```

`setupFirebaseAuthMocks();`  method I got form this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64730015/6266336

It helped to overcome similiar issue but with `Firebase#initializeCore` method.

Comment: Stop and re-run your application once.

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of the package from pub.dev and restart your application with a fresh install. Let me know if it still doesn't works

Comment: @Diwyansh, i am running just the test, will the re-run of the application have any influence on that?

Comment: There are some dependencies that complies there code when installing the app if you add such a dependency and just restart the app then it will throw No implementation error

Comment: @MuhammadHussain, I have upgraded firebase_auth to the current version and started the app. But as i mentioned before, the error doesn't occur while running the app, but when running the test....

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?