# Flutter Widget unit test firing exception

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am new to flutter unit test. I am writing a class Accounts and want to widget test.

And I am writing a test file named account_entry_page_test.dart

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('General section found', (tester) async {
    // await tester.pumpWidget( Provider<AuthBase>(
    //     create: (context) => Auth(),
    //     child:ChangeNotifierProvider<GeneralProvider>(
    //         create: (context) => GeneralProvider(),
    //         child:MaterialApp(home: Accounts()
    // ),),));

    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: Accounts()));

    final generalSection = find.text('Privacy');
    // Use the `findsOneWidget` matcher provided by flutter_test to verify
    // that the Text widgets appear exactly once in the widget tree.
    await tester.pump();
    expect(generalSection, findsOneWidget);

  });
}
```

But I am getting the test failed and getting following  exception

```
The following FirebaseException was thrown building Builder:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

Please let me know what wrong I am doing.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding Firebase.initializeApp()?

Comment: In test file ? I added it but getting different error .can you please clarify it

Comment: Please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63634609/firebase-auth-unit-testing-error-no-firebase-app

Comment: That I already looked into it . That is not the exact problem I am facing since I am only testing widget presence

Comment: But you are loading a widget which seems to depend on firebase

Comment: Yes to some extent but how to mock it that I want to know